# Identifying a bimetal thermostat from an electrical wall heater

Tags: electrical, thermostat, heating, heater

Attached are pictures of a bimetal(?) thermostat from an electric heater. The knob broke off, so I need to replace it. Does anyone know the name? Or have a link?

https://imgur.com/a/qhaC7Mo

Comment: Might be easier to work from the heater to the thermostat, than from thermostat to the heater.  Knowing the make and model of the heater makes it easier to find parts for it.

Comment: I see, thanks. It seems to be a really old heater, I don't see any model numbers, but it says "Meier" on the cover. I've attached some more pictures here: https://imgur.com/a/cANcMNq